# Unable to change the "Read more" text inside the_excerpt

Tags: loop, excerpt

I am unable to change the "Read more" text while using the excerpt. I've tried the following code:

```
 function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
 return ' <a class="read-more" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">
 Custom text</a>';
 }

 add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more' );
```

And this is how I am printing the excerpt:

```
 <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Please could you post your whole loop, the_excerpt more text should be just [..] not read more..

Comment: are you using any plugins to customize the excerpt. Also, are you sure you are have not manually set excerpt for the post?

Answer (score 3):

Try making the post object accessible using global and use get_permalink($post->ID)

```
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    global $post;
    return '<a class="read-more" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">Custom text</a>';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more' );
```

Ensure the code is in your functions.php file.

Comment: Hi @Matt.C! Thanks for your quick reply. I tried your code and still I am unable to customize the "Read more" text.

Comment: I forgot to actually make $post global in my code after mentioning it, sorry, updated answer, possibly try again?

Comment: It's not picking up the code at all... this is really weird.

Comment: hmm, are you letting wordpress generate the excerpt from the content, or using an excerpt manually put in for the post?

Comment: I'm just using the_excerpt variable to print it.